# Pegar botão especifico com Jquery em estrutura de repetição

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

```
while($reg = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
      {
         $id = $reg->id;

echo "<div class='altpost' id='$id'></div>";
        echo "<form id='$id' class='faltpost' method='post' action='altp.php'><input name='naltpost' type='number' value='$id' hidden/><button>editar</button></form>";
      }

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.faltpost').submit( function(){
            var dados = jQuery(this).serialize();
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "altp.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: dados,

                success: function(data)
                {
                    var id = $('.altpost').attr("id");
                    $(document.getElementById(id)).html(data);

                }

            });

            return false;
        });
    });
```

Quando clico em qualquer botão de qualquer postagem só ativa o efeito na primeira postagem, o problema é que os botões tem a mesmo nome, to procurando uma maneira de expecificar cada botão. Tentei jQuery('.faltpost').attr("id").submit, mas não funcionou. o "$id" é o número da postagem, estou tomando uma surra do JQUERY quem me ajudar é certo que darei pontuação.

Comment: O `div` e o `form` possuem o mesmo valor em `id`? Isso não é possível. O atributo `id` define um elemento único na página e não podem existir mais de um elemento com o mesmo `id`. Leia mais na [especificação W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute).

Comment: Pois é eu tinha colocado class e mudei pra id, esqueci disso, vou mudar para class novamente, mas o problema aqui é como especificar o botão no Jquery. Eu clico e seleciona todos os botões, porque eu não sei como eu faço para pegar um botão especifico e colocar no Jquery com o while, porque ele repete todas as postagens com class com o mesmo nome. Na hora que eu tento jogar para Jquery pega todas elas de uma vez, porque eu não consigo expecificar no Jquery:

Comment: O `submit` do formulário está funcionando corretamente? Apenas a exibição do resultado que aparece em todos os elementos?

Comment: O problema tá nessa linha aqui: "jQuery('.faltpost').submit( function(){" A classe faltpost está em todos os botões. eu quero especificar cada uma delas.

Comment: Está funcionando normalmente, mas só na primeira postagem, se eu apertar na de baixo, o efeito funciona na primeira postagem e em qualquer outra postagem a mesma coisa.

Comment: Sim, mas você precisa fazer isso, mas a função será executada apenas para o formulário que for submetido. O problema real está na função `success`. Você está sempre pegando o valor do `id` de `$('.altpost')`, que sempre será o primeiro.

Comment: A primeira vez que eu tentei eu estava fazendo da seguinte forma

Comment: success: function(data){
                    $(".altpost").html(data);

                }

Comment: Mas assim o efeito vai para todas as postagens

Comment: Tem alguma sugestão para que eu possa resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que eu te recomendaria fazer é colocar tanto a `div` quanto o formulário dentro de um mesmo elemento pai. Por exemplo:

```
<div class="result">
    <div class='altpost'></div>
    <form class='faltpost' method='post' action='altp.php'>
        <input name='naltpost' type='number' value='$id' hidden />
        <button>editar</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Desta forma, podemos fazer o código JavaScript da seguinte forma:

```
// Tratamento do evento submit do formulário:
$(".faltpost").submit(function () {

    // Objeto do formulário que foi submetido:
    var form = $(this);

    // Recupera os dados a serem enviados:
    var dados = form.serialize();

    // Envia os dados através de AJAX:
    $.ajax({
        url: "alt.php",
        method: "post",
        data: dados,
        success: function (data) {

            // Objeto da div referente ao formulário:
            var div = form.parent(".result").children(".altpost");

            // Exibe o conteúdo na div:
            div.html(data);

        }
    }); 

});
```

A questão está em fazer:

```
var div = form.parent(".result").children(".altpost");
```

Isso buscará o elemento pai do formulário que possui a classe `.result`, depois busca neste elemento um elemento filho que possui a classe `.altpost`. Desta forma, será selecionado a `div` que está junto com o formulário em `div.result`.

Comment: Vou tentar aqui! Daqui a pouco te falo se deu certo. : )

Comment: Funcionou aqui, muito obrigado! Estava há bastante tempo tentando fazer isso e não conseguia.

Comment: Eu iria dar like, mas aqui está dizendo que não dá por que eu não tenho 15 de reputação. Quando eu tiver eu dou like!